# GZIP in .net core not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm attempting to add Gzip middleware to my ASP.net core app.

I have added the following package :

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.0"

In my startup.cs for the Configure Services method I have the following :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

In my Configure method I have the following :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

However when I try and load a page, it doesn't come through as Gzip compressed. I have used both a string response and outputting a view. The response headers in chrome look like :

[image]

I am on a windows machine developing in visual studio. When running the app I have tried just running from Visual Studio (Via F5), and also using the "dotnet run" command from command line. Neither output GZip compression.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I added the Nuget package and configured it just like you did, and see the `Content-Encoding:gzip` in the response headers in chrome after I ran it from within VS 2015.

Comment: @Shiva, Are you able to pastebin your project.json for me.

Comment: Here you go. The Nuget package should automatically have added `    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.0"` dependency to your `project.json` file. Here's mine => http://pastebin.com/HeXD1GfY

Comment: I have to duck out but first thing I notice, I am targeting framework 1.1 not 1.0. Will try it in 1.0.

Comment: By default, the compression is disabled on secure connections (https). From my tests, the compression does work with `.Net core 1.1`. I also blogged about [enabling gzip compression with ASP.NET Core](http://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/2017/01/13/Enabling-gzip-compression-with-ASP-NET-Core).

Comment: @meziantou, Because I am running this locally I don't think that will be an issue (It's not HTTPS).

Comment: have the same issue

Answer (score 44):

To Enable GZIP in .net core 2.*
**1.** Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression` with `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression` command or nuget package manager.
**2.** Add the following code into `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

  app.UseResponseCompression();
  app.UseMvc();

}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

  // Configure Compression level
  services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);

  // Add Response compression services
  services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
  {
      options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
      options.EnableForHttps = true;
  });

}
```

Comment: I was missing the EnableForHttps. I wonder why the default value is false :'(

Comment: I guess it's because it mitigates the BREACH attack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH).

Comment: @pvasek you guessed right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.0#compression-with-secure-protocol

Comment: + EnableForHttps helped and order was important (put all configs on the top)

Comment: This only works in release for me. Net 6

Answer (score 13):

[The answear from Mohammad Dayyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517671/3276634)  works great for compressing the HTML body. If you want to compress also static client files like CSS or JS, the `Startup.Configure` method must look like this:

```
app.UseResponseCompression();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

It's important to place `app.UseResponseCompression()` **before** `app.UseStaticFiles()`. Otherwise the static file handler sends the ressource to the client without applying any compression.

You can also add a black/or whitelist for mime types to compress in `AddResponseCompression`:

```
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest);
services.AddResponseCompression(options => {
    options.MimeTypes = new string[]{
        "text/html",
        "text/css",
        "application/javascript",
        "text/javascript"
        // ...
    };

    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});
```

Excluding specific mime types is also possible due to the `options.ExcludedMimeTypes` property.

Yes, there are good arguments to keep such things seperated from the application server and use some reverse proxy for things like compression. This also allows the usage of the [more effective Brotli algorithm](https://medium.com/oyotech/how-brotli-compression-gave-us-37-latency-improvement-14d41e50fee4) in ASP.NET Core 2.1 LTS, which is officially only avaliable for the new 2.2 release (except custom middlewares relying on third party libraries).

This was also my first idea, but it seems that nginx 1.17.3 currently doesn't playing well with gzip and ASP.NET Core 2.1. After enabling gzip, I get randomly `FormatException: Invalid ETag name` exceptions. So it seems a suiteable workaround for me to let .NET Core do this job.

Answer (score 10):

Got this issue resolved by adding response compression option property "EnableForHttps" as shown below:

```
services.AddResponseCompression(opt =>
        {
            opt.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
            opt.EnableForHttps = true;
        });
 services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = 
 CompressionLevel.Fastest);
```

Answer (score 5):

Solved it by putting

> app.UseResponseCompression();

before

> app.UseMvc();

in Startup.Configure, i.e:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseResponseCompression(); // <--
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(); // <--
    }
```

Comment: Also before any `app.UseEndpoints( ... )`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to enable the Response Compression Middleware when using IIS Express by removing

```
<httpCompression ...> 
...
</httpCompression>
```

in .vs\config\applicationhost.config

Answer (score 0):

By placing the `UseResponseCompression` twice under each other I managed to make it work. I have no idea how this made it work. I am still looking for an accepted solution.

Comment: You sound like the OP, but the account isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. Make sure your Fiddler's "Decode" function is disabled. And you can see a yellow bar in the response.
   [Disable Decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up9Lr.png)
2. Or exit Fillder or other proxy app and have a try.