# .NET Core API response compression of file content result does not reduce response size

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling with setting up the response compression for an endpoint in .net core 6 API that returns a relatively large sqlite file (>60mb) of type application/vnd.sqlite3.

I adde necessary configuration to Startup.cs class, such as

```
app.UseResponseCompression();
```

and

```
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.MimeTypes =
                    ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "application/vnd.sqlite3" });
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });

services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.SmallestSize;
            });
```

response is returned from the controller like this:

```
return File(dataBytes, "application/vnd.sqlite3");
```

Even though response contains a header Content-Encoding with gzip/br (depending on request header), the size of a response is essentially the same as without compression.

Comment: Have u gone through these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732254/gzip-in-net-core-not-working

Comment: How do you check that it is not working?

Comment: try to compress the dataBytes manually sing some Zip lib

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, thank you - it turnt out to be postman decompressing the response automatically. I completely missed it.

Comment: @MukulKeshari, thanks - I know I can use custom code to do the compression, but wanted to use in-built one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, but do not use postman to test it. i am using Firefox for developer and it shows the transferred size!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you added compression middleware (`app.UseResponseCompression();`) in pipeline? If not, place it before controller/map middleware.
2. You added `GzipCompressionProviderOptions` but not `BrotliCompressionProviderOptions`. Test adding it.
3. Check response headers. if it is compressed you can find related header there.
4. Not everything can be compressed to reduce size so maybe your content is of this kind. try compressing it manually (use apps or something for example 7zip).

Comment: Thanks, although I did all of it. It turnt out to be postman related issue. Fiddler shows the size correctly.

Comment: I think Postman shows actual size not transferred size and It's not an issue.